# Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters From LeetCode

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, substring

Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

Input: s = "abcabcbb"
Output: 3
Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3.

```
public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
    String str = "";
    int max = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if(str.contains(Character.toString(s.charAt(i)))){
            if(max<str.length()){
                max = str.length();
            }
            i = str.indexOf(s.charAt(i));
            str = "";
        }
        else{
            str += s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    if(max<str.length()){
        max = str.length();
    }
    System.out.println(str);
    return max;
}
```

I tried to go through each character from String s and if it's not in the String str("substring of s"), I added it to str. If the character is already in str, then I save str's length in max(if max<str.length()), reset i's index to the repeated character in str and I clear str. Then i++ indicates the next character, so I can start reading new substring.

If input is: "abcbdef"
First str is: "abc". Then because 'b' is getting repeated this substring ends, i=1(first b's index), after i++ i=2(c), and str=""; From here I start my new substring.
Second str is: "cbdef"
max = 5

But if input is: "abcabcbb", it doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: For reference, this seems to be the LeetCode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/

Answer (score 0):

You're running an endless loop bacause `i` is being improperly reset. Once you find a duplicate character, you need to restart the entire process from the next character from where you started the previous process.  For example, if the string is `abcaeb` the first search starts with `a`.  Once the `a` is found, the current max will be `3` and the string will be `abc`.  Then you need to repeat the process starting with `b`.  Then `bcae` will be found.

first,
check for an empty string (or perhaps even null).

```
if (s.isBlank()) {
        return 0;
}
```

Then set `max = 1` since character is guaranteed.

There are more efficient methods but for this, just use a nested loop as shown here:

```
for (int restart = 0; restart < s.length(); restart++) {
         for (int i = restart; i < s.length(); i++) {
```

Then delete `i = str.indexOf(s.charAt(i));`

And you only need to do the following once, at the start of the inner loop.

```
  if (max < str.length()) {
      max = str.length();
  }
```

Here is the modified method.

```
public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
     if (s.isBlank()) {
        return 0;
     }
     String str = "";
     int max = 1;
     for (int restart = 0; restart < s.length(); restart++) {
         for (int i = restart; i < s.length(); i++) {
             if (str.contains(Character.toString(s.charAt(i)))) {
                  if (max < str.length()) {
                      max = str.length();
                  }
                 str = "";
             } else {
                 str += s.charAt(i);
             }
         }
     }
     return max;
 }
```

**Suggestion:**  Using a debugger can help with situations like this.  But it can take practice.  A useful alternative is to use print statements to print values at key places and see if they are what you expect.

Comment: could you explain why in my code there's an endless loop? why i is getting implemented wrong?

Comment: @AibarOtar A demo is easier.  Run your original code but put print `i, s, and str` after  your statement `i = str.indexOf(s.charAt(i));`, You will see it keeps repeating by resetting `i` back to `0`.